# Scatter plot with overlapping points plotted side-by-side

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a plot for my data using `ggplot2`. I'm looking to have a scatter plot on top of a `geom_boxplot()`, so I can display the points on top of the actual distribution.

In my data, there are a few distinct categorical values (`Year` or `Gender`) of x and a range of assay values for y. If there are points with close y values in the same x category, I'd like to plot these points side by side on a horizontal line. I've tried playing around with `geom_jitter` and `geom_point`, with `position_dodge`, `position_stack` and `position_jitter`, but I am relatively new to R and I'm unable to implement this requirement.

I'd really appreciate any help in how I should approach this problem. As of now, I'm using a `data.frame` and feeding it into a typical `ggplot2` graphing pipeline (`geom_boxplot(...) + geom_jitter(...) +` etc)

Thank you!

EDIT:

Sample Data (`df`):

```
RecNo    Gender    Value
  1       M         12.0
  2       M         13.2
  3       F         13.4
  4       M         14.5
  5       F         16.0
  6       M         19.3
  7       F         7.5
  8       M         9.7
  9       F         11.2
  10      M         15.6
```

My code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(Gender,levels=rev(levels(Gender))),Value)) 
+ stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar')
+ geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0,position=position_dodge(1),width=0.5)
+ geom_jitter(size=2,
position=position_dodge(width=0.1,height=0),show_guide=FALSE)
+ ylab("Plasma Value") +xlab(label="Gender")
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,90,5))
+ ggtitle("Distribution")
```

EDIT 2:

While the code is but an attempt of mine to get to where I wanna go, I am quite sure it is my approach and not the code that is flawed. My ultimate goal is to customize the scatter plot such that points that are too close are "stacked" side-by-side. I'd appreciate suggestions on how I should be thinking about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You will need to provide a more specific description of your problem in order to get help. Provide sample data and the code you have tried. Explain clearly _exactly_ how your code didn't work.

Comment: Sure, the data is a bit sensitive, so I'll anonymize and provide a sample. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `geom_jitter`, try `geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1),size = 2,show_guide=FALSE)`, but I'm reluctant to suggest more, since you haven't really explained in detail how your code isn't working, or how you expect it to work.

Comment: Hi, I'll try the `geom_point` like you say. Also, it's more of a thought process wall than a code problem that I'm facing. I am not sure I'm attacking the problem in the right way.

Comment: What you are describing sounds to me like a dotplot.  To see if that might be what you want, try `geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")` instead of `geom_jitter()`.

Comment: Thank you, @aosmith! I'll try experimenting with that.

Comment: @aosmith It worked! I now have a lead to work on! Could you maybe add your comment as an answer so I could accept it please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use *dot plots* on top of box plots with `geom_dotplot`.  With dot-density dot plots, points with similar values are stacked next to each other.  This gives a sense of the shape of the sample distribution beyond what just a box plot shows you.

With vertical box plots, you'll want to stack the dot plot along the y axis using the `binaxis` argument.  I often choose to use centered dot plots (with `stackdir`), as well, because I think it looks nice with the box plot.

Basic example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")
```

Comment: Thank you. I now use the `geom_dotplot` with `binwidth`, `stackdir` and `dotsize` to customize it the exact way I want the plot to look like. Thank you so much for the lead!

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggestion. I dropped the details in geom_something(). If you want to know how to use geom_***, you can use [this link](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/). I hope this sample gives you some ideas of ggplot2. Let me know if you need more help.

```
library(ggplot2)

### Create a sample data
recNo <- 1:100
gender <- rep(c("M","F"), each = 1, times = 50)
value <- runif(100, 100, 500)

foo <- data.frame(recNo,gender, value, stringsAsFactors=F)
foo$gender <- as.factor(foo$gender)

### Draw boxplots
ana <- ggplot(foo, aes(x = gender, y = value)) +
         geom_boxplot() +
         geom_jitter() +
         xlab("Gender") +
         ylab("Plasma value") +
         ggtitle("Distribution")

ana
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While I know a bit of ggplot2 - enough to understand your example, I was wondering how to tweak the jitter plot to my liking. Could I tweak it so nearby points stack horizontally - that is what I'm trying to figure out. I'd love any help on that please.

Comment: So maybe you will be interested by [this](http://denishaine.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/beeswarm-plot-with-ggplot2/).

Comment: That looks really interesting, @VincentGuillemot . Thank you so much!